# Django : Error: No module named apps - Django version 1.4.5

Tags: python, django

Python-Django newbie here, please be gentle.
I am getting error `Error: No module named apps` , while using Django version 1.4.5.
But if I upgrade to 1.8.1, I am not getting the error.
I cannot use 1.8.1 as there are some other dependencies which works only with 1.4.5 version.

/proj_folder/profiles/apps.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ProfileConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "profiles"
    verbose_name = 'User Profiles'

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals   # noqa
```

I am getting error in the above import "Unresolved import:AppConfig" with version 1.4.5.
Is there any workaround for this problem?

To state it simple, how can I backport my code to 1.4.5 version?
I started this project using a template, and when I moved forward, I had to add more components which works with 1.4

Answer (score 1):

Th [app registry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/) was introduced in django 1.7, so there is no such functionality in django 1.4.

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there any workaround for this problem, in 1.4.5? Can you please suggest similar functionalty module in 1.4.5?
To state it simple, how can I backport my code to 1.4.5 version.
I started this project using a template, and when I moved forward, I had to add more components which works with 1.4 version only

Comment: Which functionality you want to acheive?  `verbose_name`?  The only option for 1.4 is to override the admin template.